# $g(x) = f(3x + 2)$. If $f ([2, 5])$ = $[10, 20]$, what is $g([0, 1])$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Suppose we are given functions $f, g : R → R$ satisfying $g(x) = f(3x + 2)$.

(a) If $f ([2, 5])$ = $[10, 20]$, what is $g([0, 1])$?

(b) If $f^{−1}([−10, 10])$ = $[0, 2]$, what is $g^{−1}([−10, 10])$

I know that this is somehow relates to the image and preimage of a function.

I also think that for part (a) you need to find the formula to get If $f ([2, 5])$ = $[10, 20]$, so then afterwards you could apply the function of $g(x)$.

Could someone tell me how I would find the formula for $f(x)$, or point me in the right direction?

Comment: If we define $h(x)=3x+2$, what is $h([0,1])$? As you know that $g(x)=f(h(x))$, you have the answer.
If $f^{-1}([-10,10])=[0,2]$, then knowing that $g^{-1}=(f\circ h)^{-1}=h^{-1}\circ f^{-1}$, you also have the answer.

Comment: So from this we know that for part $(a)$, $g([0,1])  = [10,20]$?

Comment: Exactly, because $h([0,1])=[2,5]$ and $g=f\circ h$.

Comment: For part (b) then could you just say that $g^{-1}([-10,10]) = [0,2]$?

Comment: A priori, no. $g=f\circ h$, so that $g^{-1}=h^{-1}\circ f^{-1}$ and $h^{-1}([0,2])=\left[\frac{-2}{3},0\right]$, so that $g^{-1}([-10,10])=\left[\frac{-2}{3},0\right]$

Answer (score 0):

$g(0) = f(3*0+2) = f(2)$

$g(1) = f(3*1+2) = f(5)$

so $g([0,1]) = f([2,5]) = [10,20]$

Try to workout the second problem.

hint: $f([0,2]) = [-10,10]$